# Gitlab CI Different executor per stage

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Is it possible to have 2 stages in gitlab-ci.yml and one to be run with docker runner but the other to be run with shell?

Imagine I want to run tests in a docker container but I want to run deploy stage in shell locally in the container.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not exactly stages but you can have different **jobs** to be run by different runners using [tags](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#tags) configuration option which should give you exactly what you want.

Add (either during runner creation or later in Project settings -> Runners) tag *docker* to the Docker runner and tag *shell* to the shell runner. Then you can set the `tags` in your *.gitlab-ci.yml* file:

```
stages:
  - test
  - deploy

tests:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    - [test routine]

deployment:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - shell
  script:
    - [deployment routine]
```