# Can we run two gitlab runner with different executor on the same machine?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

a) can we  run two  gitlab runner (executor= docker and executor=shell) on the same machine?

b) Is there any way to trigger the build only when some change happens to a particular branch?

Answer (score 1):

**ad a)** Yes, you can have many runners on a build server and each of them can have its own configuration and use a different executor. You can enforce use of a particular runner using [tags](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#tags). See my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38483480/gitlab-ci-different-executor-per-stage/38490019) for more info.

**ad b)** Yes, by using the `only` configuration option.

> only defines the names of branches and tags for which the job will be
>   built.

See [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#only-and-except) for more info..